# set up existent product blocked in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm not able to change the product type (nor the  product data) into virtual as it looks its noneditable, like blocked [image]

Comment: This is probably because downloadable is checked? And you can't check the checkbox?

Comment: I can't change anything on the dashboard.

Comment: Are you an admin?

Comment: yes sure i'm admin

Comment: No idea what you did. But this does not happen on a fresh install, so I guess you installed a plug-in that is disabling this or you edited something you should not have.

Comment: recently the tables in woocommerce DB have been updated. is it for this reason? How can I change it?